# Detect if User pastes a link with jpg, gif, or png at the end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a script that detects if the URL that User pastes has 'jpg', 'gif', or 'png' at the end.

Right now I'm stuck on trying to grab the URL that User pastes, so that it can even be analyzed. Can I receive assistance?

HTML

```
<a href="www.imgur.com/dog.jpg">Link1</a>
<br>
<a href="www.digg.com">Link2</a>
<br>
<input type=text class="snax-link-url" />
```

jQuery

```
$('a[href]').filter(function() {
  return /\.(jpg|gif|png)$/.test($(this).attr('href'))
}).on('mouseover', function(){
  alert('foo');
})

$('.snax-link-url').on("paste", function(){    
alert('pasted')  ;
  
});         
var value = $('.snax-link-url').val();

if($('.snax-link-url').val() != ''){   
      alert(value);
}
```

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vh7wqrk5/1/

Comment: You need to get the value inside the `on('paste'` handler function. You are trying to get it before the event occurs. Inside can use `this.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are checking for the value of the text box when the page is loaded so it would be empty so your 2nd alert(Line:8) will be there followed by a empty alert(why empty because it is capturing the value of the textbox when the page is loaded) so what you have to do is to **get the value of the textbox when its value changes.**

```
       $('.snax-link-url').on("change", function(){
       let userString = ($('.snax-link-url').val());
       let extension= UserString.split(".").pop();
       console.log(extension);
      //Now extension will have the extension value
      //may be png , jpg, or any other
      });
```

Comment: No need to use `$('.snax-link-url')` inside the event handler. and in fact it is not a good idea... if there are more than one of that selector in the page `val()` will only return the value of the very first one which may not be the one the event occurred on. `this` is the element event occurred on

Comment: Agree with @charlietfl - Also using an onchange function on an `input type=text` is not a good idea as well. Even if the URL is pasted or typed in the input it will still expect the user to click somewhere outside to know its been changed.

Comment: One other point that makes this code ugly is the very bad practice of using global variables without scoping them using `var, let or const`

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet could help you

```js
$('input.snax-link-url').on("paste", function(e) {
  const val= e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
  console.log(val)
});
```

```html
<a href="www.imgur.com/dog.jpg">Link1</a>
<br>
<a href="www.digg.com">Link2</a>
<br>
<input type=text class="snax-link-url" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can simplify also to `const val = this.value`